# PayPal Set Custom field in Adaptivepayments SDK PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PayPal Adaptivepayments SDK PHP and using the Pay page which are shown below:

[image]

But there is no such field from where we can set custom field for tracking purpose.

Please let me know how can I set custom field in Adaptive SDK PHP (Pay).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/.
You can use Memo field or  invoiceId field.
In your screen shot, the Memo and Invoice id textbox are included.

Hope these information could be helpful.

Comment: If we are using Memo or Invoice id, it will not reflect on IPN return parameters. Please see the below IPN parameters:

Comment: transaction_subject&txn_type=&payment_date=&last_name=Srivastava&residence_country=&item_name=&payment_gross=&mc_currency=&business=&payment_type=&protection_eligibility=&verify_sign=&payer_status=&test_ipn=&tax=&payer_email=&txn_id=&quantity=&receiver_email=&first_name=&payer_id=&receiver_id=&item_number=&payer_business_name= Store&payment_status=Completed&mc_gross=1.00&custom=&charset=windows-1252&notify_version=3.8&ipn_track_id=401448a98e5fb

Comment: If you want to get the information from IPN , you can add the custom field in return or cancel URL , such as http://localhost:80/paypal/index.php?param_1=value&param_2=value